# Як адекватно перекласти українською "волосяная луковица"?

Tags: переклад

Я знаю, що це називається фолікулом. Можливо, є також україномовна назва?

Answer (score 3):

Ну, власне, у підручниках пишуть «волосяна цибулина»:

- Олійник Іванна, Галашин Ольга, Стецюк Лариса, «Вивчення біології у 9 класі. Конспекти уроків», [с. 152](https://books.google.com.ua/books?id=AMzyCgAAQBAJ&pg=PA152&dq="%D0%B2%D0%BE%D0%BB%D0%BE%D1%81%D1%8F%D0%BD%D0%B0+%D1%86%D0%B8%D0%B1%D1%83%D0%BB%D0%B8%D0%BD%D0%B0");
- Пішак В. П., Бажора Ю. І. та ін., «Медична біологія.: Підручник для ВМНЗ ІІІ-IV р.а.», [с. 517](https://books.google.com.ua/books?id=BEv5CQAAQBAJ&pg=PA517&dq="%D0%B2%D0%BE%D0%BB%D0%BE%D1%81%D1%8F%D0%BD%D0%B0+%D1%86%D0%B8%D0%B1%D1%83%D0%BB%D0%B8%D0%BD%D0%B0").

Англійською це може називатися зокрема *hair bulb*, де bulb позначає будь-який твердий предмет, що округлий з одного боку й звужується з іншого, зокрема й цибулину та лампочку, тож, можливо, це калька не з російської.

Comment: Правильне зауваження про англійську мову. Англійською та частина цибулі, що під землею так і називається *bulb*. Можна глянути на статтю [onion](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Onion), там як друга назва вказана *bulb onion*.